# Is there any EMRFS SDK to access S3 from EC2 Machine?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, emr

I've read [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-file-systems.html) and I conclude that `EMRFS` is only available if I am using `AWS EMR` machine.

I am asking this because I am interested with `EMRFS`'s read-after-write-consistency for `s3`.

Answer (score 2):

I just would like to put new input to this question: there is an in-progress community effort that provides a consistent S3 model in Hadoop: [S3Guard: Improved Consistency for S3A](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13345).

As the description mentioned:

> This issue proposes S3Guard, a new feature of S3A, to provide an option for a stronger consistency model than what is currently offered. The solution coordinates with a strongly consistent external store to resolve inconsistencies caused by the S3 eventual consistency model.

For more information, please refer to the [design doc](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12821464/S3GuardImprovedConsistencyforS3AV2.pdf).

This will be part of Hadoop distribution in the next release probably Hadoop 3.0.

UPDATE: Steve just kindly backport that to Hadoop 2.9.

Answer (score 0):

It would take a bit more manual configuration, but you can get a similar setup as EMRFS + EMR's consistent view by using the existing open-source NativeS3FileSystem alongside [Netflix's s3mper](https://github.com/Netflix/s3mper), which uses the same DynamoDB-backed configuration as EMRFS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking just for read after write consistency then you can just use S3 as-is (all regions support read after write consistency) with EMR. The catch is for US-Standard buckets just set fs.s3n.endpoint=s3-external-1.amazonaws.com in EMR and use that same endpoint on all non-EMR applications.